# Remove dotted lines in background of PowerPoint's design pages

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Recently my PowerPoint have added a dotted grid in the background of the design pages (not the running presentation).

I think it is intended to help me align stuff, but how do I remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was easy to fix.

Right click background and choose this from the context menu

```
Grid and Guides... > Gridlines
```